# How to remove the contract storage associated with instance variables?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Reading the Solidity docs:

`delete a` assigns the initial value for the type to `a`.

So, it just clears or resets the value of a variable (e.g., an integer to 0)?

I thought there was a way of removing things from storage, when it isn't needed?

Is it possible to have an instance variable that sometimes occupy bytes in storage, while at other times it takes no storage? If not, what mechanims can be used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a word of storage (i.e. all 32 bytes/256 bits) to zero is identical to removing it from storage completely: it will no longer form part of the blockchain state.  You get a refund of 15000 gas for doing this (Appendix G, *R_sclear* in the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io/): "Refund given (added into refund counter) when the storage value is set to zero from non-zero").

Note that Solidity sometimes stores multiple smaller types within one storage word (e.g. up to eight `uint32`s). To remove the word from storage, all of the component variables need to be set to zero/deleted.

#### Examples

This results in just one storage word being persisted since `x` and `y` are packed into one word:

```
contract Foo {
    uint32 x=1;
    uint32 y=2;
    function bar () {}
}
```

After calling `bar()` in the following, you will have no storage persisted:

```
contract Foo {
    uint32 x=1;
    uint32 y=2;
    function bar () {
        delete x;
        delete y;
    }
}
```

After calling `bar()` in the following, you will again have no storage persisted. It is identical to the above.

```
contract Foo {
    uint32 x=1;
    uint32 y=2;
    function bar () {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
}
```

Function `bar()` in the following will leave the whole storage word persisted (no gas refund) since `x` and `y` share the word.

```
contract Foo {
    uint32 x=1;
    uint32 y=2;
    function bar () {
        delete x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the refund counter?

Comment: A couple of operations - clearing storage, as above, and calling a contract that self-destructs - result in a refund of some gas costs. The refund counter tracks this and makes sure that any refunds are deducted from the gross gas cost of the call at the end, reducing the fee to the caller.

Comment: So, the refund counter is substrates from the gas cost of the call? Each time a contract is called, the refund counter is initialized to 0, right?

Comment: Yes.  You can read all about it in the [Yellow Paper](http://yellowpaper.io), although it's not easy to follow exactly what's going on. The refund counter is the quantity called A_r (A subscript r) in there.